# Hreflang Strategy

Tags: seo, web-development, hreflang

[image]

I have a very complex question and would like to get some help from advanced webmasters and SEO specialists :)

I have a website in both English 'website.com' and in Chinese 'website.com/cn'

I've just launched the option at the footer to change the regions for my pages to automatically propose solutions in the region I operate.

So, for example, my website is by default in English and if I select at the bottom of my page a region such as Italy, my website will still be in English but my default region will be Italy (i.e fly from Italy to England or if I click on another page it will automatically be 'send painting from Italy to...].

Now I also get the option to change my language at the bottom of my website to four different languages (es/de/fr/jp). So now I have the possibilty to have my pages in French for an italian region.

My question is how do I approach my hreflang tag strategy because for now I already have a lot of combinations between the chinese and english versions + all the regions I select and I can't imagine having more combinations if I had more languages with the new regions... #help

My code for now is (see picture)

Comment: If I were to change the language, would it change the URL? I'm curious because you state that there's only an English and Chinese version of the website, but you can change the language to es/de/fr/jp...?

Comment: Your question would benefit from a few clarifications. Why do you want to have English content with a default region of Italy, or pages in "French for an Italian region"? This is key because thinking in terms of "hreflang strategy" is a mistake; how you implement `hreflang` should simply reflect your strategy — i.e. what languages are you serving, and in what markets.

Comment: @WarrenHalderman. Yes, the Url would change to website.com/it and then website.com/es etc...

Comment: @GDav I just understood what the web dev team did. They created a parameter to change the region (but it is only a behavioral change but the URL remains the same.. so until we don't create new subdomains in different languages there is no need to add more hrefland attributes. Thank you so much for the help :)